# python3 why is print("\r"+"text") different on linux and windows terminal

Tags: linux, windows, python-3.x, console

while learning python3 i wrote a little programm that displays a ascii art bargraph on the console. im feeding this method with some randon numbers so i can see how the bargraph works in action. therefor i want it to print the bargraph over and over to the same line , NOT adding a LF.

what works fine on a linux console does not on a windows console.

WHY?! and how can i fix this for any platform?

```
for i in range(500):
    print( "\r" + getProgressBar( progressPercentage=limitedRandGen(), width=consoleWidth ), end="" )
    time.sleep(50 / 1000) # delays for x seconds
```

This Code on linux outputs every bargraph on the same single line (overwriting it over and over again, which is good). on windows somehow there is an LF after each bargraph , resulting in something like this:

```
47% [==================================================================================
45% [==============================================================================
46% [=================================================================================
42% [=========================================================================
38% [==================================================================
40% [======================================================================
40% [=====================================================================
43% [===========================================================================
46% [===============================================================================
50% [=======================================================================================
48% [====================================================================================
49% [=====================================================================================
46% [================================================================================
47% [=================================================================================
46% [================================================================================
43% [==========================================================================
43% [==========================================================================
41% [=======================================================================
45% [==============================================================================
41% [=======================================================================
44% [============================================================================
42% [=========================================================================
41% [========================================================================
44% [============================================================================
46% [================================================================================
47% [==================================================================================
```

NOTE: The getProgressBar() method just returns a string with no CR+LF at all.

Comment: I tried it with this py runner it comes with under win 7 and pure cmd + python.exe myscript.py. Same result on both

Comment: Use a simple example that people can test without modification. When I use Python 3.4 in the regular Windows 7 console, a simple `for n in range(10): print('\r%02d' % n, end=''); time.sleep(0.25)` steps through printing 00 through 09 on the same line. There's no LF.

Comment: Hmmm. Instead of your example I fill the line up to consoleWidth., which in my code is determined automatically and is set to your terminal width

Comment: uhm... i just found out something strange on windows now. the problem i described appears if i call the bargraph generator with width=consoleWidth to fill the whole like. IT WORKS JUST FINE if i set width to something less wide, like say 50 or so. for some reason it seems if the cursor touches the right margin of the console window it does LF for some reason. linux just dont it seems. so i guess ill have to do a width-1 to fix it .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the meanwhile, I found out that for some unknown reason windows adds an `LF` (as known as line wraps) if some character(s) are written to the last place within a console line.

So my code was unable to stay on the same line until I reduce the width of the print to at least `maxConsoleWidth-1`, which fixed the problem.

Comment: The console advances the cursor position after a write. If you write to the last character cell in a line, the cursor moves down a row and back to the first column. Your solution is practical.

Comment: An alternative is to use ctypes to set the cursor position, but it requires defining the `CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO` structure and calling `GetStdHandle`, `GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo`, and `SetConsoleCursorPosition`. It's probably overkill unless you really need that last column.

Answer (score 0):

The following works fine in Mac OS.

```
import sys
import time
import random

def getRandomLine():
    r = random.randrange(1,20)
    return str(r) + '% ' + '=' * random.randrange(1,20)

for i in range(20):
    print(getRandomLine().ljust(30) + '\r', end='')
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.5)
```